# Can't acccess MAAS dashboard UI

Tags: maas

I followed the [installation instructions](https://ubuntu.com/download/server/provisioning) and was unable to access the web UI properly after having logged in. The web page is stuck on "Loading MAAS..." and the dashboard is never shown.

The current MAAS installed is version 2.7. I have also tried installing version 2.6 and it pretty much resulted in the same outcome (the web UI is perpetually stuck on the message "`Unable to connect to: ws://hostname:5240/MAAS/ws`")

Relevant (maybe) info: the web UI performed a request `ws://localhost:5240/MAAS/ws?csrftoken=undefined`, but there is no csrf token cookie stored after logging in.

Comment: In general, it does not help to know which "installation instructions" you "followed". It would help us help you if you showed what you actually typed and the results. "followed" conceals the typos you made while insstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what fixed it, but it's working now.

I did `ufw allow 5240` and reauthenticated after clearing cache and cookies, then the dashboard appeared normally. Checked the cookies and this time the csrf cookie has been set.

Answer (score 0):

**csrftoken** is undefined means your not able to set csrftoken field in your cookie for Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) prevention. One of the reason is because your site is not secure i.e. you are using http instead of https. If you are on IP its okay to use http, **Just make sure to clear your cookies and disable your antivirus**